# How to interrupt threading timer?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am trying to interupt a timer in python and cannot seem to figure out why this is not working. I am expecting "false" to be printed from the last line?

```
import time
import threading

def API_Post():
    print("api post")

def sensor_timer():
    print("running timer")

def read_sensor():
    recoatCount = 0
    checkInTime = 5
    t = threading.Timer(checkInTime, sensor_timer)
    print(t.isAlive()) #expecting false
    t.start()
    print(t.isAlive()) #expecting True
    t.cancel()
    print(t.isAlive()) #expecting false


thread1 = threading.Thread(target=read_sensor)
thread1.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Timer` is a subclass of the `Thread` with simple [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/65ecc390c1fa5acdd6348ae3f9843bbdcd8870d1/Lib/threading.py#L1232). It waits the provided time by subscribing to the event `finished`. You need to use [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) on timer to guarantie that thread is actually finished:

```
def read_sensor():
   recoatCount = 0
   checkInTime = 5
   t = threading.Timer(checkInTime, sensor_timer)
   print(t.isAlive()) #expecting false
   t.start()
   print(t.isAlive()) #expecting True
   t.cancel()
   t.join()
   print(t.isAlive()) #expecting false
```